# Is it possible to discover the IP addresses of all nodes in the IOTA network?

Tags: iota-network, node, neighbors

If a node has its neighbors' IP addresses, is it possible to get them, walk to the neighbors, get *their* neighbors' IP addresses, and continue until you have a full map of the IP addresses of all the nodes in the network?

Comment: IP addresses are not shared. However, you can find your neighbouring nodes using a tool named Nelson.